# How can I prove this expression is false?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Hello,

I want to show briefly why this statement is false. I am inclined to think it is false becuase when $A^{-1}$ is multiplied three times it is not equal to $A^{-3}$. Furthermore, I am unsure if having a inverse matrix to the third power possible.

Thanks.

Comment: How to disprove: choose some matrix $A$ with actual numbers (may not want to use the identity but it might work) and show that the statement does not hold

Comment: To show a statement is false, find a counterexample

Comment: What does $A^{-3}$ mean to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First expand the right side to get$(A+A^{-1})(A+A^{-1})(A+A^{-1})$ then use the distributive property to expand.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the identity, as suggested. You'll see that 8 does not equal 2.

Comment: This sort of demonstration would solve the problem posed by the title (and you could be even more explicit in the demonstration if that's all you wanted to accomplish).  But the OP's framing of their approach suggests the real issue is difficulty understanding the problem, and your approach does nothing to help with that.